# Can an external webpage access my phonegap javascript?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am writing an iPhone app in PhoneGap. My requirement is to load an external page (like http://asd.com) in the PhoneGap webview and then a when user clicks a button on the web page, it invoke a native PhoneGap js (like the BarcodeScanner.js). ie, the "scan barcode" button will be on an external website and clicking on the button (when the page is loaded via phonegap in my app) invoke a native barcode scanner of phonegap.
I tried including the barcodeScanner.js in my webpage src and linked the button on click to the phonegap js, but it does not work! I think the scanner object is coming as null ....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will be possible. Assuming you will be using Phonegap's own InAppBrowser to open the external webpage, the only events its API allows you to listen for are 'loadstart', 'loadstop' & 'exit'. There does not appear to be any way of listening to regular page events.

Take a look at the API for more information:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowserEvent

Comment: I was able to do this. Basically every phonegap view controller (CDViewController) inherits from a UIWebview and hence self.webview.loadURL(@"http://asd.index.html") seems to work fine.